# Por qué access me devuelve una fecha erronea?

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar a saber por qué access me manda una fecha erronea?

verán mi código es el siguiente:

```
query = "select * from eventos where @FechaI between  Fecha_Inicio_PES and Fecha_Fin_PES or @FechaF between Fecha_Inicio_PES and Fecha_Fin_PES";

            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
            command2.CommandText = query;
            command2.Parameters.Add("@FechaIPES", OleDbType.Date).Value = fechaN;
            command2.Parameters.Add("@FechaFPES", OleDbType.Date).Value = fechaN2;
            command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command2.Connection = conexioni;
            dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command2);
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

donde fechaN = 24/08/2020 y fechaN2= 11/09/2020 es decir el formato es dd/mm/yyyy esta consulta la hago en access y el resultado es correcto, pero por alguna extraña razón al hacerla desde c# el resultado me sale como su hiciera fehcaN= 08/24/2020 y fechaN2 = 09/11/2020 por lo tanto el resultado es incorrecto, he tratado de cambiar el formato de las fechas algo asi:

```
string fechaformat = fechaN.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        fechaN = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaformat);
```

pero me dice que el formato es incorrecto, no sé como convertirlo a mm/dd/yyyy y mucho menos por qué access hace eso raro.
Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy desesperado! gracias de antemano.

---

ya lo intente con "-" y con "/" y con ninguna lo hace, como te decia, yo le enviaba una fecha asi "dd/mm/yyyy" y access lo cambiaba a "mm/dd/yyyy" pero esto lo hace solo cuando el día es menor a 13, si es mayor o igual, lo interpreta como día, lo que hice fue cambiar el formato "dd/mm/yyyy" a "mm/dd/yyyy" solo cuando el día era menor a 13, y la consulta en access la hizo bien. después no sé que paso, no le moví nada a access y ahora me lo cambio, si le enviaba "mm/dd/yyyy" ahora lo tomaba como "dd/mm/yyyy" por eso pensé que el tema era de access. lo único que encontré en access fue esto: [image: configuracion de access]

con el código que me adjuntaste solo tengo una duda, cómo puedo recorrer mi consulta al momento de ejecutar el cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
query = "select *from Eventos where @fecha1 between Fecha_Inicio_pes and Fecha_Fin_pes 
                        or @fecha2 between Fecha_Inicio_pes and Fecha_Fin_pes";

                OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
                command2.CommandText = query;
                command2.Parameters.Add("@fecha1", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateFI1.Value;
                command2.Parameters.Add("@fecha2", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateFF1.Value;
                command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command2.Connection = conexioni;
                dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command2);
                dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Estoy utilizando el dataset para recorrer el resultado de la consulta, con el cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); no sé cómo recorrerlo.
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y apoyo amigo.

---

Gracias amigo por tomarte el tiempo en tu respuesta. sin embargo no me funcionó, hice lo que me dijiste y no me funcionó, veras, lo que hice fue esto:

```
string fechanueva = dateFF1.Value.Date.Month.ToString() + "/" + dateFF1.Value.Date.Day.ToString() + "/" + dateFF1.Value.Date.Year.ToString();
                    DateTime fechafin = Convert.ToDateTime(fechanueva);
                    command2.Parameters.Add("@FechaF", OleDbType.Date).Value = fechafin;
```

para tratar de acomodarlo y me funcionó, pero después al hacer otros querys ahora el formato de fecha era dd/mm/yyyy y me volvio a tronar, no sé por ué access hace eso? no entiendo!!! forzosamente tengo que usar access y no un motor tipo sql, porque sé que en sql no pasaría, no sé si tú sepas por qué me pasa eso con access, gracias!!

Comment: Prueba a convertirlo en número.

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo que lo hagas directo de SQL no despues, has un `SELECT DAY(?)`, un `SELECT MONTH(?)` y un `SELECT YEAR(?)` y con un `CONCAT()` los concatenas tal que:

(Por ejemplo...)

```
SELECT CONCAT ((SELECT DAY(?) FROM...),'-',(SELECT MONTH(?) FROM...)...)FROM...
```

Perdón mi pereza para escribirlo completo... (Espero se entienda)
El resultado debería darte una columna con el formato que esperas según ordenes las tres obtenciones de datos.

Suena lioso, pero de esa forma te aseguras que cambiando de motor las veces que quieras, versión que tengas el output que te saldrá será el mismo sin errores y además no te aventuras a tener que programar con casos distintos de resultados en consultas; A no ser claro, que cambies el programa con el que trabajaste el output. Te recomiendo además que le pongas un alias para procesarlo más si lo necesitas o un `AS` para que puedas reconocer la columna de algún modo cuando te suelte el resultado la consulta. ya dentro de tu aplicación podrás ver los detalles de los rangos de fecha. y si te retarda mucho el sistema porque tienes muchos datos en sistema, también este método es aplicable a consultas, lo envuelves todo en un paréntesis y cuéntalo como una columna más sobre la que podrás trabajar.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tomarte el tiempo en tu respuesta. te dejo el detalle en la respuesta de esta pregunta, ya que no me funciono :(

Comment: bro disculpa la demora! simplemente cree una nueva base de access y se soluciono.Gracias por tu tiempo bro

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea cuestión de Access, seguramente es tema de codificación, ¿Con "problema de access" te refieres a la programación en C# verdad? siendo así no sé si tendrá algo que ver el hecho de usar "/" en las uniones, porque cuando preguntaste pusiste "-" para separar, de todas formas deberías intentar cambiarlo y ver si ese es el problema, quizá igual reconoce el "/" y no es el problema. Si sigues teniendo problemas por favor envíame el código en el que tengas fallos y lo reviso. De todas formas no sé si lo sabes pero Access tiene varios formatos de fechas aplicables a columnas, podrías intentar cambiarlos o ver exactamente que formato usa; al aplicarle un formato que tu quieras te ahorras el extraer la información.
Te recomiendo de verdad que vuelvas a tratar de usar un formato SQL para ejecutar los procesos con el output que busques obtener, de esa forma es mucho más directo lo que obtienes y luego puedes devolverle los datos del mismo modo te dejo un ejemplo (solo por si acaso) que encontré por ahí de un insert.

```
string ConnString = Utils.GetConnString();
string SqlString = "Insert Into Contacts (FirstName, LastName) Values (?,?)";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", txtLastName.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Creo que es mucho más sano así realizas luego la ejecución de la query al final luego de haber obtenido los datos de forma similar y te lo ahorras, te escribiría algo propio pero la verdad estoy atareado en Netbeans, claro he usado procesos muy similares pero no van a funcionar en este contexto, espero que igual te sirva. Y perdona que no te escriba comentarios que soy nuevo en la plataforma y aún no se me permite.

Comment: Gracias amigo, este es mi código:

Comment: Perdón amigo, te conteste con otra respuesta @Esteban Illanes

Answer (score 0):

El código que te envié es para setear datos, tiene un proceso similar solo que usa un update, trata de obtener los datos, guardarlos en variables y luego setearlos o updetearlos según necesites.

Ahora bien si quieres obtener el output debes setearlo a un tipo de "dataset" o similar, no sé bien cual será el nombre de esa estructura de datos en C# hace mucho que no lo trabajo, pero es más o menos la idea utilizar una estructura que te permita obtener por el row y por el titulo de la columna que le hayas asignado en la consulta o que venga por defecto del nombre de las tablas. si necesitas más información en un tiempito que tenga la busco.

Ahora bien, tengo algo que debería ser la solución pero está en VB, que es con lo que trabaja por default las aplicaciones de office, si te sirve te la dejo abajo del todo;  si no te dejo otra posible solucion en formato de consulta que te ayuda a cambiar las fechas al formato que gustes. Un ejemplo:

```
"SELECT TO_DATE(date_column,'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM table"
```

Si el tema central del problema es el envío de datos, usa `To_DATE()` y le das parámetros de entrada en lugar de esperarlo como salida, así modificarías tu formato al que necesita Access por defecto, ajustas para entrada y salida y en teoría la comunicación debería ir bien.

Por último te dejo el código en visual para que lo transformes solo si pudieses tener acceso a su uso:
Format(Me.Fecha, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Eso último lo seteas a una variable poniendo tu fecha y debiese transformarlo.
`Format()` es el tema central, la idea es que ingresas tu fecha y luego le ajustas el formato, solo lo ajustarías para la entrada y salida.